# how Kernel identify which ethernet port is used for NFS, out of eth0 and eth1

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, nfs

I am trying to mount file system using NFS, giving kernel cmd line parameters as "root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=x.x.x.x:/ rw ip=dhcp"
My board is having two ethernet ports eth0 and eth1, with eth1 it is mounting perfectly, but not with eth0. where should I modify to make it work with eth0. any thing with kernel config options?

Regards,
Satish.G

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you. This link points your issue.
https://community.nxp.com/thread/357837

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thank you for quick reply. What is reference document used for identifying addreses of eth1@2200 to eth1@3000 and to identify the interrupt numbers.

Comment: are you not using dts file to allocate resource at boot time?

Comment: Dts file is present in arch/powerpc/boot/dts/***.dts file  , having corrspending addreses for eth0 and eth1 , but how I can suspect the reason , is there any reference for DTS file entries.  Data sheet of corrspending controller ?